# Which JavaScript Library Can Be Utilized for Sniping QR Codes within a Web Extension?

Tags: javascript, software-development, chrome, security, qr-code

I'm currently working on a web extension project and I'm in need of a specific functionality. I'm developing an extension that needs to scan QR codes displayed on the browser screen, with a particular emphasis on a "sniping" feature.

By "sniping," I mean allowing users to select and capture a portion of the QR code displayed on the screen, which can then be processed.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could recommend a JavaScript library that provides the capability to snipe a portion of a QR code displayed on a webpageweb page within a web extension. Your insights and suggestions would be invaluable in helping me achieve this functionality